# How to set key binding to `C-c C-n`?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to set key binding for `C-c C-n` rather than `C-c n`. Is it possible?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") 'func) ;; Works
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n")   'func) ;; Works
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-n") 'func) ;; Does not do anything :-(
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are successfully binding `C-c C-n` in the global keymap, which is the lowest-priority keymap.

Some major mode binding will be taking precedence, as:

> Sequences consisting of ‘C-c’ followed by a control character or a digit are reserved for major modes.

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Key Binding Conventions`

I strongly recommend reading [this article](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs) in full.  It should clarify many things for you.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs.

Comment: My `init` file get so long and caos. I get lost what is what, what I added before. I know basics of Python, C, C++. But its really a different structure for me to understand emacs's code. I will definetly read the full article, thank your for the helpful guide.

Comment: Good catch elips overwrites it `C-c C-n runs the command flycheck-or-norm-next-error`. 
Can I unbind it in order to overwrite? I did `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-n") nil)` but it did not helped :-(

Comment: I have tried this and seems like it solved my problem `Globally override key binding in Emacs`(https://stackoverflow.com/a/683575/2402577). Maybe I should carry all my keybindings into this function .

Answer (score 2):

One of two things could be happening.
Perhaps something in your config is already bound to `C-c C-n` that overrides your definition; this is unlikely but you could test for this using `describe-key` (type `C-h k` and then `C-c C-n` at the prompt).
Otherwise something in your config is using a keybinding that starts with
`C-c C-n` but is longer. Type `C-c C-n ?` which will tell you what these longer sequences are and what is bound to them. You have to decide whether to unbind these or use a different sequence from `C-c C-n` for the function you wish to bind.

Comment: Its says: `C-c C-n runs the command flycheck-or-norm-next-error` Can I unlink it in order to overwrite into `C-c n`. I overwrite it using the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/683575/2402577